# include missing columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called tenancy with a PK account period and amount

```
TenancyPK     Accountperiod     Amount
48738562851   2018/04           1458
48738562851   2018/08           45
```

Im using this code to make all the accounting periods

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
    @EndDate    DATETIME

SELECT   @StartDate = '20110501'        
    ,@EndDate   = '20110801'


SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS MonthName
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

i want to see

```
TenancyPK     Accountperiod     Amount
48738562851   2018/04           1458
48738562851   2018/05           0
48738562851   2018/06           0
48738562851   2018/07           0
48738562851   2018/08           45
```

Comment: tenancy right outer join "accounting periods table"

Comment: do you want to have missing records for all accounting periods?

Comment: BTW, tables have _rows_ and _columns_! (Not records or fields...)

Comment: @jarlh Thanks and if i right outer join what do i link it to .

Comment: @Harshana i have added what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select @StartDate as dte,
             convert(varchar(7), @StartDate, 111) as Accountperiod  -- don't ask what "111" is
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dte),
             convert(varchar(7), dateadd(month, 1, dte), 111) as Accountperiod  -- don't ask what "111" is
      from dates
      where dte < @EndDate
     ) 
select t.TenancyPK, d.Accountperiod, coalesce(ty.amount, 0) as amount
from (select distinct TenancyPK from tenancy) t cross join
     dates d left join
     Tenancy ty
     on ty.TenancyPK = t.TenancyPK and
        ty.Accountperiod = d.Accountperiod;
```

Comment: My problem is that i want to show a column in my result that dont exist in the table , i want this line to grab the pk of the missing account period and be 0

Comment: @JD_123 . . . This returns all combinations of dates and `TenancyPK`.  Did you run the query?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a table variable with the 'Amount' column default 0.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (TenancyPK INT, AccountPeriod VARCHAR(7), Amount MONEY DEFAULT 0)
```

Then insert the records of the all financial year periods without amount calculation.
Then update the amount column using a query.

Finally

```
SELECT * 
FROM  @myTable
```